# How can I fix "Internal data stream error" generated by the Gstreamer appsrc element?

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to use appsrc element of Gstreamer on a trivial example. I am creating a buffer, filling it with dummy data and trying to send it to a fakesink. The code is a watered down version of the tutorial given in link below. It only has two elements, appsrc and fakesink. My code is also given below.

When I run this code I get "Error: Internal data stream error." I have searched for a solution and as far as I can tell, the issue is attributed to mismatch of caps between elements. I don't think this is the issue here since I only have two elements.

I have tried setting "caps" property of appsrc to NULL here, but I have also tried passing the proper "caps" property which was "audio/G729." Both have failed. Also it seems like the appsrc is fine for the first 4 chunks but then it generates an error. It is always after 4 Chunks. Not sure if that is a clue.

Also, I am running the code on an embedded system (ARM Cortex-A15) but I don't think that is related. I can succesfully stream a G729 encoded Audio file on this system via following command:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=encodedData.g729 ! 'audio/G729' ! rtpg729pay ! udpsink host=192.168.XX.XX auto-multicast=true port=5004
```

What could be the reason behind this error? How can I fix this?

Thanks for all the responses.

Link: [Link to Tutorial](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/short-cutting-the-pipeline.html?gi-language=python)

Code:

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include "glibconfig.h"
#include <stdio.h>

#define     CHUNK_SIZE          10

typedef struct gstreamstruct {
    GstElement  *pipeline, *app_source, *fakesink;
    guint       sourceid;        /* To control the GSource */
    GMainLoop   *main_loop;  /* GLib's Main Loop */
    guint       sample;
} gstreamstruct;

static gboolean busCall (GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, gpointer data)
{
    GMainLoop *loop = (GMainLoop *) data;

    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {

    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
        g_print ("End of stream\n");
        g_main_loop_quit (loop);
        break;

    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: {
        gchar  *debug;
        GError *error;

        gst_message_parse_error (msg, &error, &debug);
        g_free (debug);

        g_printerr ("Error: %s\n", error->message);
        g_error_free (error);

        g_main_loop_quit (loop);
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

static gboolean pushData (gstreamstruct *streamer)
{
    printf("--->PushData!\n");
    GstMapInfo map;
    GstBuffer *buffer;
    GstFlowReturn ret;
    guint8 *raw;
    int i;

    /* Create a new empty buffer */
    buffer = gst_buffer_new_and_alloc (CHUNK_SIZE);

    /* Set its timestamp and duration */
    GST_BUFFER_TIMESTAMP (buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale (streamer->sample, GST_SECOND, 1000);
    GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale (CHUNK_SIZE, GST_SECOND, 1000);

   //Put some dummy into buffer
    gst_buffer_map (buffer, &map, GST_MAP_WRITE);
    raw = (guint8 *)map.data;
    for(i = 0; i<CHUNK_SIZE; i++)
    {
        raw[0] = 0;
    }

    //update sample value
    streamer->sample += CHUNK_SIZE;
    printf("currentDuration: %d ms\n", streamer->sample);
    gst_buffer_unmap (buffer, &map);

    /* Push the buffer into the appsrc */
    g_signal_emit_by_name (streamer->app_source, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);

    /* Free the buffer now that we are done with it */
    gst_buffer_unref (buffer);

    if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK)
    {
    /* We got some error, stop sending data */
        printf("Data sending Failed!\n");
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}

/* This signal callback triggers when appsrc needs data.
 * Here, we add an idle handler to the mainloop to start pushing data into the appsrc
 *
 * Whenever Gstreamer goes idle, it will call this function. Maybe we can utilize this for
 * G729 etc!
 *
 * */
static void startFeed (GstElement *source, guint size, gstreamstruct *streamer)
{
    if (streamer->sourceid == 0)
    {
        g_print ("Start feeding\n");
        streamer->sourceid = g_idle_add ((GSourceFunc) pushData, streamer);
    }
}

/* This callback triggers when appsrc has enough data and we can stop sending.
 * We remove the idle handler from the mainloop */
static void stopFeed (GstElement *source, gstreamstruct *streamer)
{
    if (streamer->sourceid != 0)
    {
        g_print ("Stop feeding\n");
        g_source_remove (streamer->sourceid);
        streamer->sourceid = 0;
    }
}

void appSrcTest (void* args)
{
    printf("---> appSrcTest\n");
    gstreamstruct my_streamer;
    GstCaps *caps;
    GstBus *bus;
    //GstPad *pad;
    guint bus_watch_id;

    memset (&my_streamer, 0, sizeof (gstreamstruct));

    gst_init (NULL, NULL);
    my_streamer.main_loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);

    printf("Gst Initialized!\n");
    my_streamer.sample = 0;

    my_streamer.app_source  = gst_element_factory_make("appsrc", "appSrc");
    my_streamer.fakesink     = gst_element_factory_make("fakesink", "fakeSink");

    my_streamer.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("g729-pipeline");

    if(!my_streamer.app_source || !my_streamer.fakesink || !my_streamer.pipeline)
    {
        g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("Elements Created!\n");
    caps=NULL;
    /*
    caps = gst_caps_new_simple ("audio/G729",
                            "channels", G_TYPE_INT, 1,
                            "rate", G_TYPE_INT, 8000,
                            NULL);
    */
    //g_object_set (G_OBJECT(my_streamer.app_source), "caps", caps, "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME,     NULL);
    g_signal_connect (my_streamer.app_source, "need-data", G_CALLBACK (startFeed), &my_streamer);
    g_signal_connect (my_streamer.app_source, "enough-data", G_CALLBACK (stopFeed), &my_streamer);

    printf("Properties Set!\n");

    /* we add a message handler */
    bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus (GST_PIPELINE (my_streamer.pipeline));
    bus_watch_id = gst_bus_add_watch (bus, busCall, my_streamer.main_loop);
    gst_object_unref (bus);

    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (my_streamer.pipeline), my_streamer.app_source,     my_streamer.fakesink, NULL);
    printf("Elements Added!\n");


    printf("Pipeline Starting!\n");
    gst_element_set_state (my_streamer.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

    g_main_loop_run (my_streamer.main_loop);

    gst_element_set_state (my_streamer.pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref (my_streamer.pipeline);
    g_source_remove (bus_watch_id);
    g_main_loop_unref (my_streamer.main_loop);
}
```

The output from this code is generated as:

```
Gst Initialized!
Elements Created!
Properties Set!
Elements Added!
Pipeline Starting!
Start feeding
--->PushData!
currentDuration: 10 ms
--->PushData!
currentDuration: 20 ms
--->PushData!
currentDuration: 30 ms
--->PushData!
currentDuration: 40 ms
Error: Internal data stream error.
```

Edit: After more trials I have realized that the error is not generated after 4 Chunks consistently. When I reboot the system and call the function the error is generated after 156 Chunks for instance. After a couple more tries, the error starts occur much sooner (like 4 Chunks.) Also I have tried running the code with GST_DEBUG=2 but could not really find anything useful. Below you can find the DEBUG output.
DEBUG:

```
---> appSrcTest
Gst Initialized!
Elements Created!
Properties Set!
Elements Added!
Pipeline Starting!
Start feeding
--->PushData!
currentDuration: 10 ms
--->PushData!
currentDuration: 20 ms
--->PushData!
currentDuration: 30 ms
--->PushData!
currentDuration: 40 ms
--->PushData!
0:00:00.084280528  1344   0x18fa00 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3055:gst_base_src_loop:<appSrc> error: Internal data stream error.
currentDuration: 50 ms
--->PushData!
0:00:00.084342504  1344   0x18fa00 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3055:gst_base_src_loop:<appSrc> error: streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
currentDuration: 60 ms
--->PushData!
currentDuration: 70 ms
Error: Internal data stream error.
```

Edit 2: After further debugging I have realized that the fakesink element was not linked to appsrc. So I manually linked them via the following line

```
gst_element_link_pads (my_streamer.app_source, "src", my_streamer.fakesink, "sink");
```

I think it works fine now, I will come back again after I verify it completely.

Edit 3: Yeah, I can confirm that was the issue. I forgot to link the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to link the elements. The following line solves the issue.

```
gst_element_link_pads (my_streamer.app_source, "src", my_streamer.fakesink, "sink");
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how, but this thing worked for me:
sudo apt remove gstreamer1.0-vaapi

Comment: Apparently some decoders use video acceleration through vaapi and those decoders are less robust than CPU based ones, so removing vaapi removes the less robust and the ones left work well. Thanks for your answer!